# How to fit wide table on a page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, alignment, textwidth

I am building a table in latex but it is too wide to fit the page. Centering will only align it on the left side so that it will spill out on the right side. I already tried to rotate it and to set text width but it did not work. Every tip would be very much appreciated!

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Add caption}
       \begin{tabular}{lSSSSSSSS}
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{predicted Variable}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{step1\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step2\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step3\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step4\_coefs} \\
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{est}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{se}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{est}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{se}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{est}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{se}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{est}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{se}} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{w} & 0.145 & 0.082 & 0.205* & 0.082 & 0.225** & 0.081 & 0.161 & 0.085 \\
    \textbf{w} & -0.138*** & 0.041 & -0.103* & 0.041 & -0.116** & 0.041 & -0.134** & 0.044 \\
    \textbf{w} & -1.146*** & 0.042 & -1.135*** & 0.042 & -1.09*** & 0.042 & -1.055*** & 0.042 \\
    \textbf{w} & 0.159 & 0.103 & 0.154 & 0.103 & 0.181 & 0.101 & 0.262* & 0.103 \\
    \textbf{w} & 0.023 & 0.107 & 0.019 & 0.107 & 0.086 & 0.106 & 0.235* & 0.112 \\
    \textbf{w} & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.005 & 0.005 & -0.008 & 0.005 & -0.009 & 0.005 \\
    \textbf{w} & -0.335*** & 0.041 & -0.336*** & 0.041 & -0.331*** & 0.04  & -0.323*** & 0.04 \\
    \textbf{w} &       &       & -0.108** & 0.038 & -0.093* & 0.038 & -0.025 & 0.041 \\
    \textbf{w} &       &       & -0.159 & 0.151 & 0.03  & 0.152 & 0.035 & 0.152 \\
     \textbf{w} &       &       & 0.555*** & 0.096 & 0.515*** & 0.096 & 0.549*** & 0.096 \\
    \textbf{w} &       &       & 0.081 & 0.095 & 0.064 & 0.094 & 0.039 & 0.094 \\
     \textbf{w} &       &       &       &       & 0.397* & 0.187 & 0.324 & 0.188 \\
    \textbf{w of w} &       &       &       &       & 1.357*** & 0.211 & 1.335*** & 0.212 \\
 \textbf{w w} &       &       &       &       & 0.576*** & 0.086 & 0.474*** & 0.089 \\
 \textbf{w w} &       &       &       &       & 0.477** & 0.175 & 0.46**  & 0.175 \\
 \textbf{w} &       &       &       &       & 0.7***   & 0.134 & 0.645*** & 0.135 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.382*** & 0.101 \\
 \textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.385*** & 0.106 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & 0.307 & 0.177 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.254 & 0.132 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & 0.041 & 0.156 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.041 & 0.043 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.045 & 0.043 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.088* & 0.044 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.047 & 0.044 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.079 & 0.049 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & 0.102 & 0.089 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{$R^2$} & 0.186* &   & 0.196* &  & 0.214* &  & 0.222* &  &\\
     \textbf{$\Delta R^2$} &    &   & 0.01 &    & 0.018 &   & 0.008 &   &\\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which paper size you employ (A4? US Letter? Something else?) and how wide the horizontal margins are in your document.

Comment: how you define column `S`, is this from `siunitx`? it is not loaded in your preamble ...

Comment: @Mico Of course, I am using A4 an have not set the horizontal margins.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I am using it from siuntx, thanks for reminding me, but somehow it worked anyway.

Comment: @Julia, i realy doubt that it worked ... and since you not define options for this columns, you have uneccessary space between columns, also you have errors in column numbers (last two rows), etc. problem also are to wide the first column header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing some obvious typos and mistakes (e.g., surplus `&` symbols in the final two rows) in your code, replacing the first `\midrule` statement with four separate `\cmidrule` statements, and assuming horizontal margins of 2.5cm, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment (with a modified `X` column type for the first column, to allow line breaks as needed) and the `dcolumn` package to permit alignment on the decimal markers. (The `siunitx` package and its `S` column type can perform this form of alignment as well; however, if all you need to achieve is decimal marker alignment, loading the `siunitx` package may be a bit of overkill.)

Incidentally, the directives `\textbf{$R^2$}` and `\textbf{$\Delta R^2$}` do not **embolden** their arguments. Use either `\mathbf` (in math mode, obviously) or, better yet, don't render them in bold. Removing the `\textbf` wrappers is what I've done in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}      % 'a4paper' per the OP's comment
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose the appropriate margins
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,ragged2e} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\sym[1]{^{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Add caption} \label{add_label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{4}{d{2.5}d{1.3}} @{}}
\toprule
Predicted Variable 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{step1\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step2\_coefs} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{step3\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{step4\_coefs} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{est} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{se} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{est} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{se} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{est} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{se} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{est} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{se} \\
\midrule
\textbf{w} & 0.145 & 0.082 & 0.205\sym{*}& 0.082 & 0.225\sym{**}& 0.081 & 0.161 & 0.085 \\
\textbf{w} & -0.138\sym{***}& 0.041 & -0.103\sym{*}& 0.041 & -0.116\sym{**}& 0.041 & -0.134\sym{**}& 0.044 \\
\textbf{w} & -1.146\sym{***}& 0.042 & -1.135\sym{***}& 0.042 & -1.09\sym{***}& 0.042 & -1.055\sym{***}& 0.042 \\
\textbf{w} & 0.159 & 0.103 & 0.154 & 0.103 & 0.181 & 0.101 & 0.262\sym{*}& 0.103 \\
\textbf{w} & 0.023 & 0.107 & 0.019 & 0.107 & 0.086 & 0.106 & 0.235\sym{*}& 0.112 \\
\textbf{w} & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.005 & 0.005 & -0.008 & 0.005 & -0.009 & 0.005 \\
\textbf{w} & -0.335\sym{***}& 0.041 & -0.336\sym{***}& 0.041 & -0.331\sym{***}& 0.04  & -0.323\sym{***}& 0.04 \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{w} &       &       & -0.108\sym{**}& 0.038 & -0.093\sym{*}& 0.038 & -0.025 & 0.041 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       & -0.159 & 0.151 & 0.03  & 0.152 & 0.035 & 0.152 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       & 0.555\sym{***}& 0.096 & 0.515\sym{***}& 0.096 & 0.549\sym{***}& 0.096 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       & 0.081 & 0.095 & 0.064 & 0.094 & 0.039 & 0.094 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       & 0.397\sym{*}& 0.187 & 0.324 & 0.188 \\
\textbf{w of w} &  &       &       &       & 1.357\sym{***}& 0.211 & 1.335\sym{***}& 0.212 \\
\textbf{w w} &     &       &       &       & 0.576\sym{***}& 0.086 & 0.474\sym{***}& 0.089 \\
\textbf{w w} &     &       &       &       & 0.477\sym{**}& 0.175 & 0.46\sym{**} & 0.175 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       & 0.7\sym{***}  & 0.134 & 0.645\sym{***}& 0.135 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.382\sym{***}& 0.101 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.385\sym{***}& 0.106 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  0.307 & 0.177 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.254 & 0.132 \\ 
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  0.041 & 0.156 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.041 & 0.043 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.045 & 0.043 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.088\sym{*}& 0.044 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.047 & 0.044 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       & -0.079 & 0.049 \\
\textbf{w} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  0.102 & 0.089 \\
\midrule
$R^2$        & 0.186\sym{*}& & 0.196\sym{*}& & 0.214\sym{*}& & 0.222\sym{*}  \\
$\Delta R^2$ &             & & 0.01        & & 0.018       & & 0.008    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

with use of the package `siunitx`, defining page layout by the package `geometry`  and left to `tabular*` to define space between columns:

**edit:**
in mwe is considered [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) suggestion how to improve column spacing.

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:very impartand table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    >{\bfseries}l
                           *{4}{S[table-space-text-post=***,
                                  table-align-text-post=false,
                                  table-format=-1.3]           % <---
                                S[table-format=1.3]}           % <---
                                }
    \toprule
\normalfont\multirow{2}{11ex}[-1ex]{predicted\\ Variable}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{step1\_coefs}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{step2\_coefs}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{step3\_coefs}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{step4\_coefs} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(l){8-9}
    & {\textbf{est}} & {\textbf{se}} & {\textbf{est}} & {\textbf{se}}
    & {\textbf{est}} & {\textbf{se}} & {\textbf{est}} & {\textbf{se}} \\
    \midrule
w       &  0.145    & 0.082 &  0.205*   & 0.082 &  0.225**  & 0.081 & 0.161     & 0.085 \\
w       & -0.138*** & 0.041 & -0.103*   & 0.041 & -0.116**  & 0.041 & -0.134**  & 0.044 \\
w       & -1.146*** & 0.042 & -1.135*** & 0.042 & -1.09***  & 0.042 & -1.055*** & 0.042 \\
w       &  0.159    & 0.103 &  0.154    & 0.103 &  0.181    & 0.101 & 0.262*    & 0.103 \\
w       &  0.023    & 0.107 &  0.019    & 0.107 &  0.086    & 0.106 & 0.235*    & 0.112 \\
w       & -0.007    & 0.005 & -0.005    & 0.005 & -0.008    & 0.005 & -0.009    & 0.005 \\
w       & -0.335*** & 0.041 & -0.336*** & 0.041 & -0.331*** & 0.04  & -0.323*** & 0.04  \\
w       &           &       & -0.108**  & 0.038 & -0.093*   & 0.038 & -0.025    & 0.041 \\
w       &           &       & -0.159    & 0.151 &  0.03     & 0.152 & 0.035     & 0.152 \\
w       &           &       &  0.555*** & 0.096 &  0.515*** & 0.096 & 0.549***  & 0.096 \\
w       &           &       &  0.081    & 0.095 &  0.064    & 0.094 & 0.039     & 0.094 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &  0.397*   & 0.187 & 0.324     & 0.188 \\
w of w  &           &       &           &       &  1.357*** & 0.211 & 1.335***  & 0.212 \\
w w     &           &       &           &       &  0.576*** & 0.086 & 0.474***  & 0.089 \\
w w     &           &       &           &       &  0.477**  & 0.175 & 0.46**    & 0.175 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &  0.7***   & 0.134 & 0.645***  & 0.135 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.382*** & 0.101 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.385*** & 0.106 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & 0.307     & 0.177 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.254    & 0.132 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & 0.041     & 0.156 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.041    & 0.043 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.045    & 0.043 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.088*   & 0.044 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.047    & 0.044 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & -0.079    & 0.049 \\
w       &           &       &           &       &           &       & 0.102     & 0.089 \\
    \midrule
$R^2$   & 0.186*    &       &  0.196*   &       &  0.214*   &       & 0.222*    &       \\
$\Delta R^2$    &   &       &  0.01     &       &  0.018    &       & 0.008     &       \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. For tighter spacing of the `se` columns, consider changing the second `S` column from just `S` to `S[table-format=1.3]`.

Comment: @Mico, you are (as usual) right. considered in edited answer. thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another variant, with a slightly simpler code and a plain  `tabular`, with the help of`makecell` and `caption` for a better vertical  spacing between above caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment = center}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{lc}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering
  \caption{Add caption}
       \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\boldmath}l*{4}{S[table-space-text-post=***, table-space-text-pre = $-$]S}} %
     \makecell[l]{predicted\\ Variable}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{step1\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step2\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step3\_coefs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{step4\_coefs} \\
    \toprule
          &{\thead{est}} & {\thead{se}} & {\thead{est}} & {\thead{se}} & {\thead{est}} & {\thead{se}} & {\thead{est}} & {\thead{se}} \\
    \midrule
    w & 0.145 & 0.082 & 0.205* & 0.082 & 0.225** & 0.081 & 0.161 & 0.085 \\
    w & -0.138*** & 0.041 & -0.103* & 0.041 & -0.116** & 0.041 & -0.134** & 0.044 \\
    w & -1.146*** & 0.042 & -1.135*** & 0.042 & -1.09*** & 0.042 & -1.055*** & 0.042 \\
    w & 0.159 & 0.103 & 0.154 & 0.103 & 0.181 & 0.101 & 0.262* & 0.103 \\
    w & 0.023 & 0.107 & 0.019 & 0.107 & 0.086 & 0.106 & 0.235* & 0.112 \\
    w & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.005 & 0.005 & -0.008 & 0.005 & -0.009 & 0.005 \\
    w & -0.335*** & 0.041 & -0.336*** & 0.041 & -0.331*** & 0.04 & -0.323*** & 0.04 \\
    w & & & -0.108** & 0.038 & -0.093* & 0.038 & -0.025 & 0.041 \\
    w & & & -0.159 & 0.151 & 0.03 & 0.152 & 0.035 & 0.152 \\
    w & & & 0.555*** & 0.096 & 0.515*** & 0.096 & 0.549*** & 0.096 \\
    w & & & 0.081 & 0.095 & 0.064 & 0.094 & 0.039 & 0.094 \\
    w & & & & & 0.397* & 0.187 & 0.324 & 0.188 \\
    w of w & & & & & 1.357*** & 0.211 & 1.335*** & 0.212 \\
    w w & & & & & 0.576*** & 0.086 & 0.474*** & 0.089 \\
    w w & & & & & 0.477** & 0.175 & 0.46** & 0.175 \\
    w & & & & & 0.7*** & 0.134 & 0.645*** & 0.135 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.382*** & 0.101 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.385*** & 0.106 \\
    w & & & & & & & 0.307 & 0.177 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.254 & 0.132 \\
    w & & & & & & & 0.041 & 0.156 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.041 & 0.043 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.045 & 0.043 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.088* & 0.044 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.047 & 0.044 \\
    w & & & & & & & -0.079 & 0.049 \\
    w & & & & & & & 0.102 & 0.089 \\
        \midrule
     $R^2$ & 0.186* & & 0.196* & & 0.214* & & 0.222* & \\
      $\Delta R^2$ & & & 0.01 & & 0.018 & & 0.008 & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]